# Cannot upgrade software using a .pkg installer

Tags: macos, high-sierra, install, software-update, pkg

I have an iMac running High Sierra 10.13.6. I tried to use Google Earth a few days ago and I got an updated software message. I followed the instructions and downloaded a .pkg file. When I run the file, it appears to run normally as far as I can tell. But when it finishes the installation I get the following screen:[image: Failed Installation notice]

I thought maybe I had a virus so I tried running Malwarebytes. I got another upgrade notice so I downloaded the new version. It turned out to be another .pkg file. I ran it and it too seemed to be working fine but again I get a screen like this:

[image: Failed Installation notice]

Can someone explain what is going on? A remnant of the Google Earth failed upgrade is that I keep getting a message on my screen that looks like this:

[image: Sh error message]

This banner appears about every hour or so. While it doesn't cause problems it is very aggravating to see this continually popping up. Any help on these issues would be appreciated.

I have looked for answers elsewhere but no luck. I've restarted my machine in several different modes but nothing seems to effect this. Am I doing something wrong, or is my computer screwed up some way. Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Take a look at [this Apple page](https://discussions.apple.com/message/32193627#32193627) and see if this helps.  It appears that the Google Earth updater is not really a .pkg file.  If those comments help, I can add it as an answer.  I'm not sure it will solve the problem so I didn't add as an answer yet.

Comment: did you have Google Earth Pro ?

Comment: see this https://www.google.com/earth/download/gep/agree.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. There is a lot of info there and I'm going through it all. It definitely sounds like my problem.

Comment: I did not have Google Earth Pro. But after a couple of failed attempts at loading I went to my applications folder and Google Pro was in there.

Comment: I still get the banners about an sh file.

Comment: @Buscar웃 That's the link I used to download the update originally.

Comment: @fsb I'll go thru the link you sent and if that solves my problem I'll let you know. Of course, it may not help due to me. Nothing I can do about lack of knowledge on my part! lol

Comment: When you get to the "Installation Failed" screen, you can go to Window > Installer Log on the menu to see what error messages have been generated. Can sometimes help you track down the problem.

Comment: so you downloaded the Google Earth Pro, and it tried to update your existing version. I would say start over, delete old and install new.

Comment: Try to install something simple like https://etrecheck.com/ it is very useful software anyway, then run it to see your system report

Comment: I have Etrecheck. I'll run it now.

Comment: I deleted the Google Earth Pro and since then i've not received the annoying banner. Maybe to soon to say that problem is fixed.  I ran Etrecheck and it listed several minor problems but I'm clueless how to fix them. One problem I know I have is:"Modified sudoers file - The sudoers file has been modified. This is unusual and is sometimes evidence of malware".   But what do I do about this.